# Where can I install gems from when rubygems.org is down?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Currently Rubygems.org is down - the website reports an error, and a few gem install tasks are returning 500 errors.

Is there a mirror / backup source of gem files, or is rubygems.org essentially a single point of failure within the ruby gem installation process ?

Comment: Wouldn't mind knowing this myself. It looks like the whole of rubygems.org in down - what a pain.

Comment: FYI: rubygems.org is back up now thanks to [qrush](http://twitter.com/qrush)!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As per several folks on Twitter, add this to your Gemfile:

```
source 'https://production.cf.rubygems.org'
```

Also, if you're not using Bundler you can just run:

```
$ gem source -a 'https://production.cf.rubygems.org'
```

For the record, the folks on Twitter include:

[laizer](http://twitter.com/laizer), [iltempo](http://twitter.com/iltempo), and [jimneath](http://twitter.com/jimneath). Major thanks to them for saving my morning :)

Comment: Would be nice if I'd gotten an e-mail. Unfortunately this is the only alternative I know of personally off-hand :(

Comment: How does using a subdomain address access if they are down?

Comment: @TJChambers: The subdomain is a DNS record that points directly to the Amazon S3 bucket that hosts the gems IIRC. Using this source seems to bypass whatever has brought rubygems.org down on a few occasions. This will always be online unless Amazon itself is down.

Answer (score 1):

same issue affecting all git push to **Heroku**

solved the same was by changing the source on GemFile to the http://production.cf.rubygems.org

Answer (score 1):

Mirror for Asia/Pacific Region: [`https://ruby.taobao.org/`](https://ruby.taobao.org/) (recommended, high availability, syncing every 15 min)

Other mirrors:

```
https://gems.cloudafrica.net/
https://tokyo-m.rubygems.org/
```

Comment: https://ruby.taobao.org/ has migrated to https://gems.ruby-china.org/ (happened in mid-2016).

Answer (score 0):

Having experienced my share of flaky network connections I find I've most often got the .gem files I need on my system, it's just a matter of finding them and installing them locally.

Use the `find` command to find local `.gem` files and install them directly with `gem install [file]`.

```
find ~/.rbenv/versions -type f -name 'minitest*.gem'
```

That works for individual gems but if you need to install dependencies, etc. it can be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got the gem on some other computer, or on other rubies on the same
computer, use
`gem server`
to create your own gem server.

Otherwise, download the source code for the gem in question from github, and do
the rake task to build the gem.